# get('url') operation using AngularJS and ServiceStack webservice

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-services, servicestack

I am very new to AngularJS, and I am trying to get some items in JSON from a webservice I quickly made using ServiceStack. When I try the URL in the browser I can see the JSON object, but for some reason AngularJS fails to successfully get the data. Here's my implementation:

```
angular.module('SomeApp', []).controller('ItemsFetcher', [ '$http', function($http){

      var x = this;

      x.products= [
          {
            Name: 'Missing items',
            Description: 'Could not access server'
          }];

    $http.get('http://localhost:29029/json/reply/GetAllItemsRequest')
    .then(function(data){

      x.products = [
          {
            Name: 'Success',
            Description: 'Great stuff!'
          }];
      });
  }]);
```

Here's the view:

```
<html ng-app="SomeApp">
<head>
    <title>My First App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ItemsFetcher as fetcher">
    <h3>PRODUCTS</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in fetcher.products">
        <div>{{item.Name}} - {{item.Description}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As I said, if I call http://localhost:29029/json/reply/GetAllItemsRequest in a browser, I can the JSON object.

Am I missing something ? Any ideas why this does not work ?

Comment: Looks like your not referencing the data callback in the 'then' promise you have going. Console out 'data' after your http call and you should see the json object. Then use that to value and set to x

Comment: I added the error handler and I can see that the error is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.". As I understand, it means that I cannot make requests to services that are hosted in a different domain. I will try host my website and webservice in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone could benefit from this, I had to either enable CORS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or to host both the webservice and website in the same place.